# load table in table - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table border="2" class="table">
    <tr> <td class="clicked">aaa </td> <td class="clicked">bbb </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td class="clicked">ccc </td> <td class="clicked">ddd </td> </tr>
</table>

<table border="2" class="tablehide">
    <tr> <td> 111</td> </tr>
</table>



.table td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px
}

.tablehide td {
    width: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    display:none;
}


$(".clicked").live('click', function() {
    $(this).load($('.tablehide'))
    });
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/5neff/2/

I would like: if i clicked for example bbb then instead of **bbb**  load

```
<table border="2" class="tablehide">
    <tr> <td> 111</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td> 222</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your jquery to the following:

```
$(".clicked").live('click', function() {
    $(this).html($('.tablehide'));
    $('.tablehide td').show();
});
```

Live link : http://jsfiddle.net/5neff/3/

OR you can clone it to make duplicates, by using `.clone()`:

```
$(".clicked").live('click', function() {
    $(this).html($('.tablehide:last').clone());
    $('.tablehide:not(:last) td').show();
});
```

Live link : http://jsfiddle.net/5neff/4/

What basically happens is, setting the current clicked item's html to the hidden table, and then making the html from table visible.

**UPDATE [Keeping old data]**

```
$(".clicked").live('click', function() {
    $(".clicked").find('div:first').show();
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="hide">');
    $(this).find('div:first').hide()
    $(this).prepend($('.tablehide'));
    $('.tablehide td').show();
});
```

Live link : http://jsfiddle.net/5neff/7/

**UPDATE [On table click hide and keeping old data]**

```
$(".clicked").live('click', function() {
    $(".clicked .tablehide").remove();
    $(".clicked").find('div:first').show();
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="hide">');
    $(this).find('div:first').hide()
    $(this).prepend($('.tablehide:last').clone());
    $('.clicked .tablehide td').show();
});


$(".tablehide").live('mouseup', function() {
    $(".clicked .tablehide").remove();
    $(".clicked div.hide").show();
});
```

Live link : http://jsfiddle.net/5neff/8/

Comment: if i choose AAA this is good, but if then i choose BBB then in AAA is still new table

Comment: Updated, please see my answer for latest.

Comment: very, very thanks! :) and what if i click of the same TD? then this is not change, and not back for other show

Comment: better if i clicked outside this tablehide then tablehide is hide :)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this instead:

```
$(".clicked").live('click', function() {
    $(this).html($('.tablehide').html())
});
```

[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is used to load data from the server, not manipulate the currently loaded document.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/RhXPC/2/) of the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Change your JS to

```
$(".clicked").live('click',function(){
    $(this).html($('.tablehide').html());
});
```

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function is to load data (JSON, etc... for Ajax) or bind a event handler, not for get the html from an element.

Answer (score 1):

Or better yet (shortest version of all):

```
$(".clicked").live('click', function() {
    $(this).html($('.tablehide').show().html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

check the updated solution

http://jsfiddle.net/5neff/6/

```
 $('.clicked').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        htmlVal = $('.tablehide')[0].outerHTML;
        $(this).html(htmlVal);
        $(this).find(".tablehide").css("display","block");
        $(this).find(".tablehide td").css("display","block");
    });
  });
```